# Warning: mail() [function.mail]: SMTP server response: 550

Tags: php, sendmail

i am using php and mail function , but i face this error:

> Warning: mail() [function.mail]: SMTP server response: 550  No such user here in C:\inetpub\vhosts\saj.ir\subdomains\lms\httpdocs\registration\include.php on line 78

my code is :

```
$srting= "testing email";
ini_set("SMTP","webmail.saj.ir");
ini_set("sendmail_from","info@saj.ir");
$headers= 'MIME-Version: 1.0' . "\r\n";
$headers.= 'Content-type: text/html; charset=utf8' . "\r\n";
$headers .= 'From: www.saj.ir' . "\r\n";
mail("ayoob.khodadadi@gmail.com","class list",$srting,$header);
```

i don't know
thanks .

> i change `webmail.saj.ir` to `http://ns1.easysoftco.com` and now i face this message : 
>   Failed to connect to mailserver at "http://ns1.easysoftco.com" port 25, verify your "SMTP" and "smtp_port"

oh i found my problem : i am using widows and IIS 7.5
is there way to mail in IIS 7.5

Comment: Is webmail.saj.ir an SMTP server you can use as a relay? Is this running on a Windows machine? (The SMTP ini setting is ONLY for Windows)

Comment: thanks Emil i change webmail.saj.ir to `http://ns1.easysoftco.com` .

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have defined `$headers` and you are using `$header`

```
$srting= "testing email";
ini_set("SMTP","http://ns1.easysoftco.com");
ini_set("sendmail_from","info@saj.ir");
$headers= 'MIME-Version: 1.0' . "\r\n";
$headers.= 'Content-type: text/html; charset=utf8' . "\r\n";
$headers .= 'From: www.saj.ir' . "\r\n";
mail("salman_k18@yahoo.com","class list",$srting,$headers);
```

Comment: thanks salman , i change $header to $headers but still view same error.

Comment: Try running it in a separate file having only the code mentioned above, if it works fine than reverse Engineer your code

Comment: hi Salman , i replace your code but i still face same error . thanks .

Comment: you face same problem if you create a separate.php which has only the code given above ???

Comment: yes , i upload this code in test.php with this address 
http://www.lms.saj.ir/registration/test.php

Comment: You probably did'nt change my id i am receiving all the mails